# Suppose we have $v_1, \ v_2 , \cdots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^7$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have $v_1, \ v_2 , \cdots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^7$ and let $ \text{Span} (v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_k)=\mathbb{R}^7$.

What is smallest value of $k$ so that we have

$$ \text{Span} (v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_k)=\mathbb{R}^7.$$

**Answer:**

My intuition says $k=7$, but I can not explain it.

Help me to explain it.

Comment: Dimension is 7?

Comment: There is a theorem that says all basis have the same size. It is crucial for the definition of dimension of a vector space.

Comment: Does $n=7$? Because if $n>7$, there is no answer. If $n\le 7$, then $k=n$.

Comment: Say $v_i = (i,0,0,0,0,0,0)$, then  $ \text{Span} (v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_k)=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo, but $\text{ Span}$ may not be a basis. So basis do not solve the given problem

Comment: I believe you have a typo where you mean $\mathbb{R}^7$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise your set equality does not make sense equating elements from n=7 to general n.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR the span of a basis is a superset of the span of any subset of elements from the span. So, when you are asking for the smallest number of vectors needed to span a vector space, that number is the smallest number of elements needed for a basis.

Comment: @DaveNine, yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is meant to find the smallest $k$ so that

$$\text{span}\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_k\} = \mathbb{R^7},$$

notice that $\dim(\mathbb{R}^7) = 7$, so any basis (which is also the smallest spanning set) must contain 7 vectors.

You can also reference the Spanning Set Theorem. If we DID have more than 7 vectors, we can always throw away the ones that are a linear combination of the others until reaching a smallest spanning set (the basis).

Comment: The answer to this really depends on knowing what you know at this point in your course. I think the spanning set theorem does the job.